# Craftcms route is not working in local, but it's working on server

Tags: craftcms

How are you?
Yesterday, I deployed craftcms project 2.9.2 on my local. But the route is not working for me.
For example, if I type as localhost in my browser(http://localhost), it's working but if I click any item on the home page(http://localhost/collection), it's not working, I'm facing Not Found page as default. This project is working on a cloud server.
I'm not sure why it's not working when routing.
Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible something's misconfigured.

I'd start with the env looking for a base url that needs fixed.

I'd go to the site settings if you haven't got the base url in your env

Then I'd log in to craft and check the sections.  If the paths have a full url baked in then you'll have issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try again as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out my .env file had the dev server public paths set to = `"http://localhost:9090"`, but they needed to be `https`.

Once I set them to `"https://localhost:9090"` the routing worked.